# Bisection method with recursive approach?

Tags: c

I tried to write a program of bisection method with recursive apporach but it seems not working.

The function is f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c.
The parameters in findroot: a b and c are values of a b and c in f(x)
p and q indicate the interval (p,q). Assume the input are valid(can always find an answer). Here is my attempt

```
int sign(float a, float b,float c,float d)
{
   if (a*d*d + b*d + c > 0) {return 1;}
   if (a*d*d + b*d + c < 0) {return -1;}
   else {return 0;}
}

float find_root(float a, float b, float c, float p, float q)
{
   if (sign(a,b,c,(p+q)/2) == 0){return (p+q)/2;}

   else if (! sign(a,b,c,(p+q)/2) == sign(a,b,c,p))
   {return find_root(a,b,c,p,(p+q)/2);}

   else 
   {return find_root(a,b,c,(p+q)/2,q);}
}
```

Any correction or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Editing your own post with the answer and deleting the quesiton is not good.  Better to revert your post to the previous and post your own answer.  You could even accept your own answer of btter yet the fine answer provided by @r

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling this line is the problem:

```
else if (! sign(a,b,c,(p+q)/2) == sign(a,b,c,p))
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
else if (! (sign(a,b,c,(p+q)/2) == sign(a,b,c,p)))
```

or

```
else if ( sign(a,b,c,(p+q)/2) != sign(a,b,c,p) )
```